# Bulk create keys in Redis - ServiceStack C#

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

Is there any way to bulk-create keys (`SETS`) in "*Redis ServiceStack client*"? Of course, without putting  `for` loop.

There is one command in Redis which does this: [MSET](http://redis.io/commands/mset) but, I couldn't find any implementation of this command in **`ServiceStack.Redis`** client.

*Ex:*

```
MSET key1 "val1" key2 "val2"
```

**UPDATE:**
@mythz suggested a way to create multiple SETS but with single member [SETALL()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/4fa0ceb0a6f6417a06ab8c2290d32abb97800e99/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisClient.cs#L217-L261).
Additionally, I found a way to bulk add members to a single set by  [AddRangeToSet(string setId, List items)](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisClient_Set.cs)

But, is there any way I can add multiple MEMBERS while bulk creating SETS.
Something like

```
  XXXCOMMAND key1 "val11","val12","val13" key2 "val21","val22"
```

Comment: Isn't it just method `SetAll()`, as listed here https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/IRedisClient?

Comment: this command internally does the for loop https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/16cdeda7b54776d62fc11f0ec29cb615bb3e87b3/src/ServiceStack.Redis/BasicRedisClientManager.cs

Comment: I fail to see a loop in execution flow started in (https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/16cdeda7b54776d62fc11f0ec29cb615bb3e87b3/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisClient.cs#L251). Firstly, byte arrays are created, then are merged with command MSET, then sent. I assume, that by loop you mean running command in a loop for every key.

Comment: @JerryGoyal you're looking at the wrong implementation, that's off `BasicRedisClientManager` not `RedisClient` which is what's used.

Comment: please check the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SetValues` or `SetAll` APIs in ServiceStack.Redis which [batches all keys into a single MSET operation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/4fa0ceb0a6f6417a06ab8c2290d32abb97800e99/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisClient.cs#L217-L261), e.g:

```
var map = new Dictionary<string,string> {
  {"key1","val1"},
  {"key2","val2"},
  {"key3","val3"},
};

redis.SetAll(map);
```

Most operations in ServiceStack.Redis that take a collection are sent in either a single operation or when it doesn't exist batched in a pipeline and sent as a single Network write.

Comment: This is fine for bulk adding single member per set.. is there any way to bulk add multiple memebers to multiple set? something like MSADD key1 "val11", "val12","val13"  key2 "val21","val22","val23"

Comment: @JerryGoyal this isn't adding to any SET it's adding multiple Key/Values using Redis MSET bulk command. MSADD isn't a valid Redis command and [no SET command exists](http://redis.io/commands#set) that adds members to multiple sets. You could use a Transaction or Pipeline to call `AddRangeToSet()` in a single pipeline.